# Вопрос позиционирования flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы списки встали друг под другом? Т.е. список 5 встал по высоте под списком 2 и не равнялся на высоту список 1.

```css
.flex-wrap{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex-wrap ul{
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px;

}
.flex-wrap ul li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
<ul>
  <li>Cписок 1</li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Cписок 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Cписок 3</li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Cписок 4</li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="title">Cписок 5</li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Cписок 6</li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй колонки. Только порядок элементов надо будет поменять.

```css
section {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>Cписок 1</li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Cписок 2</li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Cписок 3</li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Cписок 4</li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="title">Cписок 5</li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Cписок 6</li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
  </ul>
<section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-wrap{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1170px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-wrap ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px;

}
.flex-wrap ul li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
    <div class="listGoup">
        <ul>
            <li>Cписок 1</li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Cписок 4</li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="listGoup">
        <ul>
            <li>Cписок 2</li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Cписок 5</li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="listGoup">
        <ul>
            <li>Cписок 3</li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Cписок 6</li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```